# Programmatically generate MySites for all users

Tags: my-site, console-application, userprofiles

I have a console application with the following piece of code:

```
SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(portalSite);
UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
foreach (UserProfile u in profileManager)
{
     if (u.PersonalSite == null)
     {        
        try
        {       
            portalSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            portalSite.RootWeb.EnsureUser(u["AccountName"].ToString());
            u.CreatePersonalSite();
            portalSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
     }
}
```

**It works only for users who already logged in on the portal once before.** I got the following error when I run that script for **some** users who didn't have access yet to the environment. The code crashes at "EnsureUser()".

[image]

If I skip the "EnsureUser()" method, the code crashes on the "CreatePersonalSite()" method with a **PersonalSiteCreateException**.

As far as I know, the "EnsureUser()" will ensure that the user exists. When a user enters the portal for the first time - a new record will be created in the [User Information List](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/06/25/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list.aspx). If we use this method after a user logged in for the first time, the user will exist. The same goes up for the u.CreatePersonalSite(). Is this correct? Am I missing something?

How can I create mysites for profiles who didn't access the portal before?
Thanks in advance!!!!

*Edit: I changed "poralSite" in the code fragment to "portalSite"*

Comment: What is `portalSite`? Your MySite Host? Another site? If it's not the MySite Host, I'd try ensuring the user there first.

Comment: Can you check the ULS logs to see if there are any other details about the error generated on the CreatePersonalSite() method?

Comment: @James: portalSite = intranet site collection; I already tried to pass the MySite Host as an SPSite obj , but no help...
I haven't done both though - ensure user on both site collections...

Comment: @Mike: I'll check this later - but I have my doubts that the ULS logs will provide more useful info; Thx

Comment: Pre creating my sites is a **really* bad idea, and considered a bad practice. You end up with a lot of site collections to maintain that will probably never be used..

Answer (score 2):

**SPWeb.EnsureUser** works in conjunction with membership and role providers which are configured in web.config and so You will need *HttpContext*( or *SPContext*) for it. Normally, It will not work in console application because *HttpContext* in console app is null!

It will work in codebehind of a webpage in the site collection as *HttpContext* is available.

To use *SPWeb.EnsureUser* in console application, you will need to

1. Create *app.config* for console application.
2. Copy the *system.web>rolemanager* and *system.web>memebership*
   sections in app.config
3. Try to run console application with above *app.config* settings.

Comment: Thanks Amit for your answer, but I don't use a custom membership / role provider. 

As stated in the post of Mastykarz - You only need that extra web.config if you have a custom membership / role provider

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-programmatically-sharepoint-users-spweb-ensureuser/

Comment: Are you able to manually add those users(who didn't access the portal before) in any of the site groups?

Comment: Yes that works...

Answer (score -1):

It is the problem with your console application where SPContext won't be there . You can create SPSite collection with URL and try directly.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://myspsURL"))
{
    serviceContext serviceContext= ServerContext.GetContext(site);
    UserProfileManager userprofileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
    UserProfile u = profileManager.GetUserProfile(sAccount);
    u.CreatePersonalSite();
    foreach (UserProfile u in profileManager)
    {
        if (u.PersonalSite == null)
        {        
            try
            {   bool allowsafeupdate = portalSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates 
                //http://solutionarchitects.org/articles/2011/02/24/better-way-to-do-spweb-allowunsafeupdates.htm   
                portalSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                portalSite.RootWeb.EnsureUser(u["AccountName"].ToString());
                u.CreatePersonalSite();
                portalSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowsafeupdate ;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how to format my answer :)

Comment: ServerContext is obsolete in SP2010, We should use SPServiceContext instead. Anyway, SPContext cannot be established in this manner.

Comment: @Rajesh: I already pass an SPSite object to the SPServiceContext method - to create 'a context'